# What are the green spots on our kitchen walls

Tags: walls, concrete, painting, paint

Our kitchen has one of the main walls of our house which is a thick concrete wall. There is nothing behind the wall, just some empty space and then the neighbor's house. I just painted the wall with Flexa indoor water-based color, as grey.

Now, as you can see in the pictures, after a couple of months we see some green spots on the wall in different places.

[image]

[image]

My question is, what are these green spots? They don't look like mold or mildew.

**Update**

- I just tested our cleaning sprays on the wall to see if it happens because of some spray drops but it was not the case.
- This place is not reachable for our kids.

Comment: Looks like some kind of deliberate marker

Comment: Is this in an area where children might have splashed something on it like lime Kool-aid or colored with a marker?

Comment: They are not in a reachable place for our kids and we have many of these spots.

Comment: That is a bold comment. I have a neighbor kid over here last week manage to get orange soda pop spray on everything within 4 feet. :)

Comment: What is the actual wall surface? Obviously that's not bare concrete. Also, what's the scale of those photos?

Comment: @isherwood I don't know the exact material on the surface but yes there is a layer on the concrete. I took the photo from a close distance like 20 cm so, the spots are small.

Comment: Is that on the surface or did it leach from beneath?  Perhaps you can dig in a bit wit a pin to find out.  If you put a drop of bleach on it and it disappears, it's mildew.

Comment: Simple fix:  Be color-blind.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like copper corrosion products - so if there is a bit of copper embedded inthe wall, this sort of staining to the surface is quite plausible. WHY there's copper there to cause staining, I can't tell you.

Comment: Maybe someone was pressure-treating wood in the area and for one reason or another it splashed?

Comment: Pressure treating is not a DIY operation and most of the DIY preservatives don't have copper, IME. I'm thinking "copper nails" but having a hard time figuring why anyone would have put copper nails in a masonry wall, so I'm back to I Don't Know but Looks Like Copper...

Comment: I certainly did not mean to imply industrial pressure treatment. I was implying the DIY route with a Copper Naphthenate application. I wasn't sure if "preserving wood" is the proper explanation of using such a product so I figured "pressure-treating" would be more universally understood.

Comment: Copper sulfate is sometimes used in fungicide for house plants. It's a stretch, but that could be an explanation.